# use custome zone in woocommerce in wordpress plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

so this is my code

```
function crudStatesOperations() {
        global $wpdb;
        $country_code = 'no';

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'states';
        if (isset($_POST['newsubmit'])) {
         add_filter('woocommerce_states', function ($states)  {

                $states['BB'] = array(
        'BB001' => 'St. George',
        'BB002' => 'St. Michael',
        'BB003' => 'Christ Church',
        'BB004' => 'St. Philip',
        'BB005' => 'St. Lucy',
        'BB006' => 'St. Joseph',
        'BB007' => 'St. Peter',
        'BB008' => 'St. James',
        'BB009' => 'St. Thomas',
        'BB0010' => 'St. John',
        'BB0011' => 'St. Andrew',
    );

                return $states;

            });
        }
}
```

and add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'woo_custom_shipping_zones' );
its not working inside in my function but if i put it outside and reactivate my plugin its working

how can use this filter inside the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**Wordpress options**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) to solve the problem:

```
// if the "$_POST['newsubmit']" field is set, update the "add_custom_states_woocommerce" option
function crudStatesOperations() {
    global $wpdb;
    $country_code = 'no';
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'states';
    if ( isset( $_POST['newsubmit'] ) ) {
        update_option( 'add_custom_states_woocommerce', true );
    }
}

// adds custom states based on "add_custom_states_woocommerce" option
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'woo_custom_shipping_zones', 10, 1 );
function woo_custom_shipping_zones( $states ) {

    if ( get_option( 'add_custom_states_woocommerce' ) ) {
        $states['BB'] = array(
            'BB001'  => 'St. George',
            'BB002'  => 'St. Michael',
            'BB003'  => 'Christ Church',
            'BB004'  => 'St. Philip',
            'BB005'  => 'St. Lucy',
            'BB006'  => 'St. Joseph',
            'BB007'  => 'St. Peter',
            'BB008'  => 'St. James',
            'BB009'  => 'St. Thomas',
            'BB0010' => 'St. John',
            'BB0011' => 'St. Andrew',
        );
    }

    return $states;

}
```

*The code should work. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: how can i send variables that available in crudStatesOperations and send to woo_custom_shipping_zones function?

Comment: You can create an option that will have as its value an array with all the variables you want to pass from one function to another. Look here for an example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51841/200545